# Laravel giving 404 with HTTP Requests only when serving with Apache

Tags: apache, laravel

When I serve with "php artisan serve" it works flawlessly, but when I am serving with apache the HTTP requests gives me 404 errors.

This is what the console gives me:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('index');
});

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function() {

    Route::resource('comments', 'CommentsController', 
        array('only' => array('index', 'store', 'show', 'destroy')));
});

App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return View::make('index');
});
```

htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

apache2.conf:

```
<Directory /var/www/app/public/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

added the line in sites-available/000-default.conf:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/app/public/
```

I am following this tutorial:
http://scotch.io/tutorials/php/create-a-laravel-and-angular-single-page-comment-application

Comment: Give example of url that gives you 404, and also post the code that defines this route in routes.php?

Comment: I followed this tutorial: http://scotch.io/tutorials/php/create-a-laravel-and-angular-single-page-comment-application the error comes in the index file

Comment: Did you reload Apache after changing the config files?

Comment: Yes I did restart apache and also tried restarting virtualbox where the vm is running.